# Specificity and sensitivity in a retrospective clinical diagnosis study: How many samples do I need?

Tags: statistical-power, clinical-trials

I would like to analyse the survival at 2 years after undergoing 1 of 3 diagnostic methods for diagnosing two related conditions: condition IBD (can respond to drug A) or condition SLC (can respond to drug A + drug B).

**Diagnosis options for the consultant:**

- Empirical diagnosis: Treat with drug A or drug A + drug B and see what happens (cheap and non-invasive)
- Diagnosis through biopsy: Endoscopy + biopsy + molecular test (expensive and invasive)
- Diagnosis through thymidine kinase assay (cheaper and non-invasive)

In a retrospective study, I'd like to know how many patients I need in each diagnosis group to assess specificity and sensitivity of each diagnosis method. A [similar](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/jsap.12494) prospective trial had 77 patients but that only had 2 groups. Is there a particular survival analysis you would recommend as I'm not sure how to set up the contingency table?

Comment: It is unclear whether yours is going to be a controlled study, a prognostic study, or a diagnostic study. Sample size computations strongly depend on the ultimate goal and study design.

Comment: Good point. Ultimately, we'd like to see really whether it's worth paying $€¥£ for endoscopy+++ when a TK assay would suffice. So are the survival rates the same in both animal groups and is the diagnostic as sensitive. What is your feeling about all this?

Comment: Cost-effectiveness is complex in itself and modeling it versus survival is even tougher. I suggest you to focus first on effectiveness using a dichotomous endpoint, and compute sample size accordingly. Then you can move from that.

Comment: So looking at the binary outcome of survival at 2 years, how would you conduct the sample size calculation based on the two different diseases and 3 diagnostic methods?  Would you use probability of survival given IBD and Diagnostic method A vs probability of survival given IBD and diagnostic method B? And take the largest size that it gives form all pairwise comparisons? But survival won't differ depending on diagnostic, its whether they diagnose correctly or not. I'm not clear in my mind about what to do. Happy to give bounty or bounty bars as you prefer. Thank you.

Comment: I think you need to go step by step... moving from a diagnostic study to an RCT-like study is a tough call (eg https://www.springer.com/la/book/9783319789651). Though, I recommend you first to hypothesize the differences in sensitivity/specificity, then how they impact on management and the ensuing outcome, and finally, using this last estimates, build a sample size computation for survival analysis with 3 groups. Quite a Pindaric flight, so clinically the best thing would be first to conduct a pilot trial, probably...

Comment: Hi Joe_74. Re-reading your comment makes more and more sense. Looks like I need 5 more rep points to give bounty (bounty bars have no such restriction if you'd like to Skype?). I've just checked the library at my institution and we don't have the text unfortunately. So to summarise, 1. Evaluate specificity/sensitivity for each method. 2. Investigate how patient management is affected by each diagnostic tool. 3. Do a survival analysis. How do factor in that I've got 2 diseases to deal with, not just 1?

Comment: You need to break down each step. Regarding multiple diseases and tests, simply penalize the chosen p value.